# Let $k$ be a field and $A$ a finitely generated $k$-algebra. Show that, if $A$ is a field, then $A$ is a finite extension of $k$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, extension-field

Can anyone help me with the following question?

> Let $k$ be a field and $A$ a finitely generated $k$-algebra. Show that, if $A$ is a field, then $A$ is a finite extension of $k$.

I see that $\phi: k \to A$ is injective since $k$ is a field. So, $\frac{k}{(0)} \cong k \cong \phi(k) \subseteq A$. But I am stuck formalizing that $A$ is indeed a finite extension of $k$.

Comment: Do you know anything about Noether Normalization?

Comment: This is the so called Zariski's lemma. One proof appears in Atiyah-Macdonald, proposition $7.9$. Depends what tools do you have. To be honest, it's surprising you got that as an exercise, that's a very important and nontrivial result.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! Sorry for my ignorance on the topic... maybe I'm a few pages behind the necessary tools